# post using httpClient Asp.net core 2.0 and angular5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0, angular5

i have a controller webapi class with an httpPost action,

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddBrokerContact( [FromBody] BrokerContact broker)
 {
     if (broker!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(broker.BrokerFirstName)) {         
          _context.Add(broker);
          await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
          return CreatedAtAction("Post", broker);
     }
     else
     {
       return BadRequest("Need More Data");
     }
 }
```

My problem is that when i make a request from angular5 using httpClient i get the broker object as null in the controller, this is my service class

```
AddnewBrokerContact(broker: BrokerClass): Observable<BrokerClass> {
  var headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  return this.http.post<BrokerClass>(this.baseUrl + 'api/BrokerContact/AddBrokerContact', broker, { headers});
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post the data with Postman and see it work?

Comment: I now whats the problem, i am using a class instead of an interface, for some reason, with and BrokerInterface works just fine, so i will study whats the difference and why that happen, Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using and interface instead of a Class in the service method solve my problem, Thanks

```
AddnewBrokerContact(broker: BrokerInterface): Observable<BrokerInterface> {
  var headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  return this.http.post<BrokerInterface>(this.baseUrl + 'api/BrokerContact/AddBrokerContact', broker, { headers});
}
```